# Communications link failure when connecting to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am fetching data from MySQL using JAVA JDBC driver.

Following exception is occurring:

> "Communications link failure. The last packet successfully received
>   from the server was 14,380,298 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent
>   successfully to the server was 14,380,634 milliseconds ago.".

This error is occurring alternatively. That means if I run this for the first time no exception occur, but in the second time this exception occur. Then in the third run no exception give, in forth one again exception happen. I am using **TimerTask** to run the program every **four hours**.

Communication between the program and database works correctly when it run without exceptions.

Code is as follows:

```
public class CreatePO extends TimerTask {

    public CreatePO() {
        handler = new RFCHandler();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            System.out.println("Run Create PO");
            getItemFromDB();
            sendDataToSap();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void getItemFromDB() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Run get items from DB");
        Connection connection = null;

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));

        String queryOne = "SELECT reference_no, vendor_acc_no, date, mat_no,"
                + "po_qty, po_unit_measure, rate, order_price_unit, plant, user_name, email_id "
                + "FROM tbl_po_data WHERE status <> 'X'";

        try {
            pooler = DBPool_POSMS.getInstance();
            dataSource1 = pooler.getDataSource();
            System.out.println("PO pooler");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println(" : PO pooler error");
        }

        try {
            connection = dataSource1.getConnection();
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);

            Statement st = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(queryOne);

            int lineitem = 0;

            rs.last();
            rcount = rs.getRow();
            rs.beforeFirst();
            System.out.println("rcount = " + rcount);

            System.out.println("PO while loop");
            itemData = new Object[11][rcount];

            if (rcount > 0) {

                while (rs.next()) {
                    itemData[0][lineitem] = rs.getString("reference_no");
                    itemData[1][lineitem] = rs.getString("vendor_acc_no");
                    itemData[2][lineitem] = rs.getDate("date");
                    itemData[3][lineitem] = rs.getString("mat_no");
                    itemData[4][lineitem] = rs.getString("po_qty");
                    itemData[5][lineitem] = rs.getString("po_unit_measure");
                    itemData[6][lineitem] = rs.getString("rate");
                    itemData[7][lineitem] = rs.getString("order_price_unit");
                    itemData[8][lineitem] = rs.getString("plant");
                    itemData[9][lineitem] = rs.getString("user_name");
                    itemData[10][lineitem] = rs.getString("email_id");
                    lineitem = lineitem + 1;
                }

                rs.close();
                st.close();

            }

        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println(" : PO while loop error");
            e1.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            try {

                connection.close();
                System.out.println("Close connection one");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println(" : Connection close error");
            }
        }

    }

    private void sendDataToSap() {

        System.out.println("Send Data to Sap");
        Table IT_LIST = null;
        Table IT_RESPONSE = null;

        try {

            if (rcount > 0) {



                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            handler.releaseClient();
            System.out.println(e + " : Handler release error");
        }

        finally {
            rcount = 0;
        }

    }
```

Exception...

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 14,380,298 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 14,380,634 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3743)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2506)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2677)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:4842)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.setAutoCommit(DelegatingConnection.java:371)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.setAutoCommit(PoolingDataSource.java:328)
    at CreatePO.getItemFromDB(CreatePO.java:84)
    at CreatePO.run(CreatePO.java:53)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3725)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: Instead of using `rcount`, why don't you rely on the `rs.next()`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your connection was open too long and was closed by MySQL server (as indicated by the *"Connection reset by peer: socket write error"* in the stacktrace). You need to configure your connection pool to either close too old connections, validate (test) the connection before handing it out or a combination of that.

You could also try increasing the timeout configuration in MySQL, but to be honest, a connection that was open for close to 4 hours (14 million milliseconds) may just need to be closed.

Comment: but i am closing my connection in the finally block.

Comment: @D.Madu If you use a connection pool, then closing the connection returns it to the pool for reuse. The 14 million milliseconds in the exception make clear that the connection has been open (and unused) for close to 4 hours.